# AWS CDK Synth Error: failed to connect: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp

Tags: python, npm, aws-lambda, containers, aws-cdk

The aws cdk stack I am trying to cdk synth + deploy works on another laptop but I am getting the below error on this one (so i know the stack file builds and is okay).

Tried using both a docker container, and a podman container, both giving the same error.

Using:
Python3.10,
CDK version: 2.87.0,
NPM version: 8.19.2,
Node version: 20.4.0

```
> Bundling asset 
MyStack/MyStateMachine/MyFunctions/MyFunction/MyFunctionLambdaRequirementsLayer/Code/Stage...
> Error: failed to connect: ssh: handshake failed: 
read tcp 127.0.0.1:58234->127.0.0.1:55927: read: connection reset by peer
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: Error: Failed to bundle asset 
IRRStack/IRRStateMachine/GetIRRFunctions/GetRipeFunction/GetRipeFunctionLambdaRequirementsLayer/Code/Stage, 
bundle output is located at /Users/adam/qwerty/project/cdk.out/asset.b7aeaeaa9c0e91bd5913593f650fd118f36c464cc3c0ecca3f41e0bc9bb066ba-error: 
Error: docker exited with status 1
  --> Command: docker run --rm -u root -v "/Users/adam/qwerty/project/my_lambda:/asset-input:delegated" -v "/Users/adam/qwerty/project/cdk.out/asset.b7aeaeaa9c0e91bd5913593f650fd118f36c464cc3c0ecca3f41e0bc9bb066ba:/asset-output:delegated" -w "/asset-input" "public.ecr.aws/sam/build-python3.10" bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t /asset-output/python && cp -au . /asset-output"
      at AssetStaging.bundle (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:2:603)
      at AssetStaging.stageByBundling (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:4544)
      at stageThisAsset (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:2005)
      at Cache.obtain (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/private/cache.js:1:242)
      at new AssetStaging (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/core/lib/asset-staging.js:1:2400)
      at new Asset (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-s3-assets/lib/asset.js:1:736)
      at AssetCode.bind (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/code.js:1:4628)
      at new LayerVersion (/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/jsii-kernel-PdO5Tc/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda/lib/layers.js:1:2066)
      at Kernel._Kernel_create (/private/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/tmp_vtbtcnz/lib/program.js:10002:25)
      at Kernel.create (/private/var/folders/z5/8q6kn4sx0ys1mk1qs8v0bscw0000gn/T/tmp_vtbtcnz/lib/program.js:9673:93)
```

Comment: Hard to debug without any details about this asset. How are you defining the bundling for this asset?